# Add the field 'Associate to Company' on register form

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, customer, customer-account

I would like to add a mandatory field on my register form in front.

The field is 'Associate a company' exactly like the field in admin when I want to edit a customer :

[image: Admin field]

I checked the 'vendor/magento/module-company/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml' to find the field 'extension_attributes.company_attributes.company_id' so I think it should be done easily but I have no idea how.

I also check the block 'Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company' but it's for adresses.

Thank you !

Comment: you can add a custom attribute for 'customer_edit_form' .